# javascript - adjust speed of the slide toggle when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could someone help with this code.

Overview

- Have a table which shows/hides the tr

see code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb0c56na/)

```
<table>
    <tr class="title">
        <td>Column1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td> content > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis nibh ullamcorper, ultrices leo quis, ultricies ex. Suspendisse pulvinar facilisis nulla, eu fringilla ante congue non. Phasellus bibendum interdum ligula sit amet consectetur. Ut facilisis urna tempor libero convallis sollicitudin. In malesuada sollicitudin urna sit amet molestie. Aliquam ut facilisis massa. Nunc diam eros, lobortis sit amet libero in, luctus volutpat est. Duis egestas at ligula ac ullamcorper. Sed eleifend ac diam vel aliquam. Nam in fringilla urna. Vivamus porttitor dictum arcu ut congue. Vestibulum egestas dolor ut neque tincidunt maximus. Maecenas quis congue nisi. </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Question:

- could someone show me how to adjust the speed of the slide toggle?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can pass time to the slideToggle method. refer http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

```
    $(function(){
        $('.title').click(function(){
            $(this).nextUntil('tr.title').slideToggle(10);
        });
    });
```

Comment: tried this but didn't make any change in the jsfiddle code provided.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The most easiest way to do this is to use css.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr class="title">
        <td>Column1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td> content > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis nibh ullamcorper, ultrices leo quis, ultricies ex. Suspendisse pulvinar facilisis nulla, eu fringilla ante congue non. Phasellus bibendum interdum ligula sit amet consectetur. Ut facilisis urna tempor libero convallis sollicitudin. In malesuada sollicitudin urna sit amet molestie. Aliquam ut facilisis massa. Nunc diam eros, lobortis sit amet libero in, luctus volutpat est. Duis egestas at ligula ac ullamcorper. Sed eleifend ac diam vel aliquam. Nam in fringilla urna. Vivamus porttitor dictum arcu ut congue. Vestibulum egestas dolor ut neque tincidunt maximus. Maecenas quis congue nisi. </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.title').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

CSS

```
tr.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

tr.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you the reply but was looking more sliding speed rather than transition appearance speed.